# Flutter Marking locations (Latitude, Longitude) on Flutter Map from Sqflite Database

Tags: flutter, marker, sqflite

I have list of latitude and longitude which I am storing them in database.I want those latitude and longitude to be represented in flutter map with markers.

My code for saving latitude and longitude using sqlite

homeScreen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget { 
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Note> items = new List();
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();

  LatLng _center ;
  Position currentLocation;

  MapController _mapctl = MapController();


  Future<Position> locateUser() async {
    try{
      return await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    }on PlatformException catch(e){
      currentLocation = null;
    }
    return currentLocation;
  }

  getUserLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await locateUser();
    setState(() {
      _center = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
    });
    print('center $_center');
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserLocation();
     db.getAllNotes().then((notes) {
      setState(() {
        notes.forEach((note) {
          items.add(Note.fromMap(note));
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var markers = <Marker>[
      Marker(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        point: LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946),
        builder: (ctx) => Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.location_on,color: Colors.green[700],size: 30,),
            ),
      ),
      Marker(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        point: LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946),
        builder: (ctx) => Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.location_on)
            ),
      ),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Plants Watch'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UserProfile()));
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).dispatch(
                LoggedOut(),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new FlutterMap(
            mapController: _mapctl,
                options: new MapOptions(
                  center: new LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946),
                  maxZoom: 20.0,
                ),
                layers: [
                  new TileLayerOptions(
                    urlTemplate: "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/"
                    "{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token={accessToken}",
                    additionalOptions: {
                      'accessToken': 'accessToken',
                      'id': 'mapbox.streets',
                      },
                    ),
                  MarkerLayerOptions(markers: markers)
                  ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
                      child: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _mapctl.move(_center,16.0);
                        },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
                      child: Icon(Icons.add),
                      heroTag: null,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NoteScreen(Note('', '', ''))));
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
            )
           ),
        ),
      ],
    )
  );
 }
}
```

Listview.dart

```
class ListViewNote extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new ListViewNoteState();
}

class ListViewNoteState extends State<ListViewNote> {
  List<Note> items = new List();
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    db.getAllNotes().then((notes) {
      setState(() {
        notes.forEach((note) {
          items.add(Note.fromMap(note));
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Plant List',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search,
            color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){
            showSearch(context: context, 
            delegate: DataSearch(this.items));
          })
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Dismissible(
              background: stackBehindDismiss(),
              key: ObjectKey(items[position]),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 2.0,
                margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0,vertical: 2.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        '${items[position].title}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                          ),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          '${items[position].description}' + '' + '${items[position].location}',
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            ),
                          ), 
                          onTap: () => _navigateToNote(context, items[position]),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onDismissed: (dirction){
                  var item   = items.elementAt(position);
                  _deleteNote(context, items[position], position);
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text("Item deleted"),
                    ));
                  },
              );
            }
         ),
         ),
         floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
           backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
           child: Icon(Icons.add),
           onPressed: () => _createNewNote(context),
          ),
      );
    }
    void _deleteNote(BuildContext context, Note note, int position) async {
      db.deleteNote(note.id).then((notes) {
       setState(() {
         items.removeAt(position);
         });
        });
      }
    void _navigateToNote(BuildContext context, Note note) async {
      String result = await Navigator.push(
        context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NoteScreen(note)),
        );
        if (result == 'update') {
          db.getAllNotes().then((notes) {
            setState(() {
              items.clear();
              notes.forEach((note) {
                items.add(Note.fromMap(note));
                });
              });
            });
          }
        }
    void _createNewNote(BuildContext context) async {
      String result = await Navigator.push(
        context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NoteScreen(Note('', '', ''))),
        );
        if (result == 'save') {
          db.getAllNotes().then((notes) {
            setState(() {
              items.clear();
              notes.forEach((note) {
                items.add(Note.fromMap(note));
                });
              });
            });
          }
        }
     stackBehindDismiss() {
       return Container(
         alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
         color: Colors.green[700],
         child: Icon(
           Icons.delete,
           color: Colors.white,
          ),
        );
       }                
 }

class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<Note> {
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();
  List<Note> items = new List();
  final List<Note> suggestion = new List();
  // ListViewNoteState i = ListViewNoteState();

   DataSearch(this.items);    

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    assert(theme != null);
    return theme;
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () {
        query = '';

      } )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        progress: transitionAnimation,
      ),
      onPressed: (){
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(query);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestion = query.isEmpty 
    ? items 
    : items.where((target) => target.title.startsWith(query)).toList();
    if(items.isEmpty)
    {
      print("Null");
    }
     // return Text('$suggestion');
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestion.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, position){
        return new  ListTile(
            title: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: suggestion[position].title.substring(0,query.length),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: suggestion[position].title.substring(query.length),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54)
                    )
                  ]
              ),
            )
          );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my databse classes where i am creating dbHelper and class note for creating table

dbHelper.dart

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = new DatabaseHelper.internal();

  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

  final String tableNote = 'noteTable';
  final String columnId = 'id';
  final String columnLocation = 'location';
  final String columnTitle = 'title';
  final String columnDescription = 'description';

  static Database _db;

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();

    return _db;
  }

  initDb() async {
    String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'notes.db');

//    await deleteDatabase(path); // just for testing

    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $tableNote($columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,$columnLocation TEXT, $columnTitle TEXT, $columnDescription TEXT)');
  }

  Future<int> saveNote(Note note) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.insert(tableNote, note.toMap());
//    var result = await dbClient.rawInsert(
//        'INSERT INTO $tableNote ($columnTitle, $columnDescription) VALUES (\'${note.title}\', \'${note.description}\')');

    return result;
  }

  Future<List> getAllNotes() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.query(tableNote, columns: [columnId, columnLocation , columnTitle, columnDescription]);
//    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableNote');

    return result.toList();
  }

  Future<int> getCount() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableNote'));
  }

  Future<Note> getNote(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> result = await dbClient.query(tableNote,
        columns: [columnId, columnLocation , columnTitle, columnDescription],
        where: '$columnId = ?',
        whereArgs: [id]);
//    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableNote WHERE $columnId = $id');

    if (result.length > 0) {
      return new Note.fromMap(result.first);
    }

    return null;
  }

  Future<int> deleteNote(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.delete(tableNote, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
//    return await dbClient.rawDelete('DELETE FROM $tableNote WHERE $columnId = $id');
  }

  Future<int> updateNote(Note note) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.update(tableNote, note.toMap(), where: "$columnId = ?", whereArgs: [note.id]);
//    return await dbClient.rawUpdate(
//        'UPDATE $tableNote SET $columnTitle = \'${note.title}\', $columnDescription = \'${note.description}\' WHERE $columnId = ${note.id}');
  }

  Future close() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

classNote.dart

```
class Note {
  int _id;
  String _location;
  String _title;
  String _description;

  Note(this._location,this._title, this._description);

  Note.map(dynamic obj) {
    this._id = obj['id'];
    this._location = obj['location'];
    this._title = obj['title'];
    this._description = obj['description'];
  }

  int get id => _id;
  String get location => _location;
  String get title => _title;
  String get description => _description;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (_id != null) {
      map['id'] = _id;
    }
    map['location'] = _location;
    map['title'] = _title;
    map['description'] = _description;

    return map;
  }

  Note.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this._id = map['id'];
    this._location = map ['location'];
    this._title = map['title'];
    this._description = map['description'];
  }
}
```

AddItem.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'dbhelper.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class NoteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Note note;
  NoteScreen(this.note);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _NoteScreenState();
}

class _NoteScreenState extends State<NoteScreen> {
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();

  TextEditingController _titleController;
  TextEditingController _descriptionController;
  TextEditingController _locationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserLocation();
    _titleController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.note.title);
    _descriptionController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.note.description);
    _locationController = new TextEditingController(text: widget.note.location);
  }

  LatLng _center ;
  Position currentLocation;

  Future<Position> locateUser() async {
    try{
      return await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    }on PlatformException catch(e){
      currentLocation = null;
    }
    return currentLocation;
  }

  getUserLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await locateUser();
    setState(() {
      _center = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
      _locationController.text = _center.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add Plant'),
        actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.view_list),
              tooltip: 'Next choice',
              onPressed: () {
              navigateToPlantList();
              },
              ),
          ]
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                  controller: _locationController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Current location',
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
              TextField(
                controller: _titleController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                ),
                Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                TextField(
                  controller: _descriptionController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: (widget.note.id != null) ? Text('Update') : Text('Add'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (widget.note.id != null) {
                        db.updateNote(Note.fromMap({
                          'id': widget.note.id,
                          'location': _locationController.text,
                          'title': _titleController.text,
                          'description': _descriptionController.text
                          })).then((_) {
                            Navigator.pop(context, 'update');
                            });
                            }else {
                              db.saveNote(Note(_locationController.text,_titleController.text, _descriptionController.text)).then((_) {
                                Navigator.pop(context, 'save');
                                });
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                void navigateToPlantList() {
                   Navigator.push(context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ListViewNote()),);
                }
}
```

Now using this I want to written marker in my home screen

Comment: Have you tried following this course: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter?

It explains how to use Google Maps with Flutter and how to set markers on the map.

The `GoogleMap` widget contains a property `markers` where you can pass a set of markers which you read from your SQLite database to be displayed.

Comment: Yes I have gone through it but in my case I am getting real time location and storing along with some other data, from that data I want to get the location markers.I have updated my code above please go through it.@MartinNiederl

Comment: and I am not using google map instead I am using **[flutter map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map/versions/0.5.3+1#-readme-tab-)** package

Comment: What is the problem of the code, or what do you want us to fix for you? Please explain what the exact problem is because the code basically looks like you know what you do.

Comment: I want to use location data which I am saving in database and I want pass the list of location data to markers and show the markers in homescreen of the map.So could you help me in doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should store latitude and longitude as two separate real value columns. This simplifies further steps.

Then you need a list of markers which can be updated later as field in the class:

```dart
List<Marker> _markers = [];
```

To update the markers (e. g. from the database) a function is used:

```
void setMarkers() async {
  var notes = await db.getAllNotes();

  List<Marker> markers = notes.map((n) {
    LatLng point = LatLng(n.latitude, n.longitude);

    return Marker(
      width: 80.0,
      height: 80.0,
      point: point,
      builder: (ctx) => Container(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.location_on,
              color: Colors.green[700],
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
    );
  }).toList();

  setState(() {
    _markers.clear();
    _markers = markers;
  });
}
```

This function fetches all Notes from the database and updates the Markers.

In the FlutterMap widget replace the list of markers with the `_markers` field:

```dart
MarkerLayerOptions(markers: _markers)
```

To ensure, that all items are loaded shortly after the app started, call the `setMarkers()` function in `initState()` and to add a new Marker, which can be created in your NoteScreen widget, to the map replace the call from your FloatingActionButton of the HomeScreen with

```
onPressed: () async {
  await Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPlantScreen(Plant.empty())));
  setMarkers();
},
```

This updates the map after a new entry was created.

**Note:** Clearing and fully reloading the data every time from the database is not the best way, but this is up to you to optimize.

### Edit #1:

You do get the current location separated:

```
  void getCurrentPosition() async {
    Position currentLocation = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState(() {
      _center = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
    });
  }
```

What you need to do in order for that to work is update your Note class to support a `double _latitude;` and `double _longitude;` instead of `String _location;` So you need to update the map functions, the getters and the constructor.

Furthermore, you need to adjust your DatabaseHelper class:

```
final String columnLatitude = 'latitude';
final String columnLongitude = 'longitude';

// new create table statement
'CREATE TABLE $tableNote($columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $columnLatitude REAL, $columnLongitude REAL, $columnTitle TEXT, $columnDescription TEXT)'
```

And of course, all requests to the database must be adapted to the new fields so that no errors occur.

Comment: The answer looks clean and I have tried to store lat&lang as separate but I am unable to store the latitude and longitude as separate values as I am getting both as a single value by calling current location, could you please suggest me how to store lat&lang as separate values in database. It would be a great help.

Comment: If you still have questions, please contact me at the official https://fluttercommunity.slack.com, with a direct message and upvote / accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I don't 50 reputations to upvote, however I have upvoted your answer but it wont reflect here. How can I join fluttercommunity.slack.com. Can you send me invite link